# How to border-collapse for bootstrap inputs?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

As title,

I tried to create a block of inputs, where each input will be just next to each other, table-like-style as in the image below.

[image: stacked input]

The code for above is

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 padding-sides-none">
            <div class="col-xs-3 padding-sides-none">
                <select class="form-control selectpicker">
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 padding-sides-none">
                <select class="form-control selectpicker"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 padding-sides-none">
                <select class="form-control selectpicker"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 padding-sides-none">
                <input class="form-control" /> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 padding-sides-none">
            <div class="col-xs-2 padding-sides-none">
                <div class='input-group date' style="width:100%;">
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" data-date-format="DD.MM.YYYY" style="width:100%;" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 padding-sides-none">
                <div class='input-group date' style="width:100%;">
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" data-date-    format="DD.MM.YYYY" style="width:100%;" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 padding-sides-none">
                <div class='input-group date' style="width:100%;">
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" data-date-format="DD.MM.YYYY" style="width:100%;" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 padding-sides-none">
               <input class="form-control"></input>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

*Select is using bootstrap-select while datepicker uses bootstrap-datetimepicker, and using Bootstrap 3.3.0.*

Problem is the input border, which looks thicker when each input is on each other's side. The border side which touches the other inputs is somewhat thicker.

I want the touching sides of each input to be in border-collapse style, just like the border-collapse for table, where each border side will have the same thickness, but i just can't seem to get it done properly.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Border collapsing is a table-only thing. So unless you want to overwrite the whole BS grid with display:table(-*) stuff here, I think using negative margins to get two adjoining borders to “overlap” might be your best bet here. (Or, for a fixed & known number of inputs per row per breakpoint, you could of course also explicitly disable the unwanted borders, using :nth-child selectors.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
i resolved your problem
please check below code

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<style>
    .formSection .nopadding {padding: 0;}
    .formSection .form-control {border-radius: 0;}
    .formSection select.form-control {border-bottom: 0;border-right: 0;}
    .formSection .col-xs-3 input.form-control {border-bottom: 0;}
    .formSection .input-group-addon {min-width: 36px;border-right: 0; border-radius: 0;}
    .formSection .input-group {display: flex;}
</style>
<div class="formSection">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 padding-sides-none">
            <div class="col-xs-3 nopadding">
                <select class="form-control selectpicker">
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 nopadding">
                <select class="form-control selectpicker"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 nopadding">
                <select class="form-control selectpicker"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 nopadding">
                <input class="form-control" /> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 padding-sides-none">
            <div class="col-xs-2 nopadding">
                <div class='input-group date' style="width:100%;">
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" data-date-format="DD.MM.YYYY" style="width:100%;" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 nopadding">
                <div class='input-group date' style="width:100%;">
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" data-date-    format="DD.MM.YYYY" style="width:100%;" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 nopadding">
                <div class='input-group date' style="width:100%;">
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" data-date-format="DD.MM.YYYY" style="width:100%;" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 nopadding">
               <input class="form-control"></input>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

With few minor modifications to your code and with some css you can get the expected result, please check the working example below:

note: select-box `appearance` is set to none to clear the default ui provided by browser.

```css
.row.compact-row {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}
.row.compact-row > [class^="col-"],
.row.compact-row > [class*=" col-"] {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: -1px 0 0 -1px;
}
.compact-row .input-group-addon {
  border-radius: 0;
}
.compact-row .form-control {
  border-radius: 0;
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<br/><br/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row compact-row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <select class="form-control selectpicker">
        <option value="">Option 1</option>
        <option value="">Option 2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <select class="form-control selectpicker">
        <option value="">Option 1</option>
        <option value="">Option 2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <select class="form-control selectpicker">
        <option value="">Option 1</option>
        <option value="">Option 2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <input class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <div class="input-group date">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" data-date-format="DD.MM.YYYY" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <div class="input-group date">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" data-date- format="DD.MM.YYYY" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <div class="input-group date">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" data-date-format="DD.MM.YYYY" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```